# Textbooks for algebraic invariant theory

Tags: reference-request, invariant-theory

I'm currently learning algebraic invariant theory from Hilbert's lectures (Theory of algebraic invariants) and while I find them very clear and enjoyable, they don't have any exercises and I'm also interested in modern viewpoints. Could someone recommend a source of exercises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only one I am familar with is Dolgachev's Lectures on invariant theory. Much more books can be found in: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/166/resources-on-invariant-theory